# Compton compositor not working in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, compton

I have **Lubuntu 14.04 64 bits** with a **R9 380 GPU** with propietary drivers (**15.302**). I had in my repositories *ppa:richardgv/compton* and *ppa:kelleyk/compton* right now.
I can't make Compton compositor work in my machine, I have followed several tutorials from the web with no luck. I have edited:

```
~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
~/.config/openbox/autostart
/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

and added a simple @compton -c -r 16 -l -24 -t -12 -G -b wich looks fine for me, logout and login and no special effects for me. I then deleted all those lines from the autostart files (wich where empty before adding anything) and used *Preferences>LXSession* for default apps and added compton in compositer manager empty box, reloaded, and the right mouse button messed up and did nothing, could not open menus or open other apps, only terminal, so I deleted the compton option in **LXSession**, and everything went back to normal. 
How can I make compton compositor work in my machine?